# How can I find the exact value using xpath in selenium webdriver for text that contains &nbsp;?

Tags: selenium, xpath, exact-match, non-breaking-characters

I'm having an issue selecting the exact text 'Section' from the code using xpath.

** To be clear I require the exact text selection to be made from the innerText or innerHTML of the element if that is possible, not the id.  **

I'm able to use the contains text function, but that results in other partial matches that contain 'Section' being returned/highlighted as well:

```
//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul/li[contains(text(),'Section')]
```

I've tried using the following methods, but I don't know if I've got the syntax correct, as nothing is returned/highlighted:

```
//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul/li[text()='Section')]

//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul/li[.='Section']

//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul/li[normalize-space(.)='Section']
```

This is what is shown when inspecting the Section node:

```
<li id="GOS--/40" class="nodecollapsed item parent-node xh-highlight" style="" xpath="1">
                                Section&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>
                            </li>
```

This is what is shown in the element properties:

```
id: "GOS--/40"
innerHTML: "↵                                Section&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>↵                            "
innerText: " Section "
```

Here is the xml which shows the other partial matches that are returned:

```
<div class="selection-list-dialog modal-dialog Dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header SectionHeader">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <span class="modal-title" data-lang="StandardItems">Standard Items</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body selection-list-container" style="margin-top: 30px" id="base">
            <div>
                <span data-lang="SelectItemInstructions">Select the items you are interested in from the list.</span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="pull-left selection-tree-container">
                <h4 class="selection-list-title">
                    <span data-lang="Available">Available</span>                    
                </h4>
                <ul class="selection-list selection-tree-list">



                            <li id="CS--/14" class="nodecollapsed item parent-node">
                                Country Section&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>
                            </li>                        


                            <li id="Sec1--/23" class="nodecollapsed item parent-node">
                                Section 1&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>
                            </li>


                            <li id="Sec2--/24" class="nodecollapsed item parent-node">
                                Section 2&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>
                            </li>


                            <li id="GOS--/40" class="nodecollapsed item parent-node">
                                Section&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>
                            </li>


                            <li id="RS--/43" class="nodecollapsed item parent-node">
                                Regional Section&nbsp;<span class="child-count"></span>
                            </li>
```

Comment: Since the value texts is heavily formatted, you can use the starts-with or contains xpath property.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _selecting the exact text 'Section'_? Are you trying to extract the text **Section**?

Comment: I'm already using contains and that returns multiple options, which is the problem.  Starts with I wasn't sure how to use in the above, it returned nothing.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @DebanjanB I require the exact text as there are other partial matches when using contain function, whereas I require the exact match in order to click on it.  I've added some further information to my question

Comment: @DebanjanB I've not changed my question as such, I've added further information for the same question.  I was asked by one of the commenters to add in the xml for the issue above, it wouldn't fit within the comment box, hence I updated the question to include it.

Comment: The additional HTML will make all the existing answers invalid which will not be helpful to future readers.

Comment: It's not additional HTML, it is the HTML for the issue that I'm having just in it's original format, instead of the short format that I posted it in.  Those answers were already invalid as they didn't answer the question as I was asking.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[id='GOS--/40']").text` , this was my output `Section `

Comment: @supputuri where would I input this? As I was currently using Xpath helper to check which xpath selects the item

Comment: You can test this in the line the browser console. `document.querySelector("li[id='GOS--/40']").textContent`

Comment: @supputuri This returned the text from the node: "↵ Section  All | None East↵ East Midlands↵ London↵ North East↵ North West↵ Northern Ireland↵ Scotland↵ South East↵ South West↵ Wales↵ West Midlands↵ Yorkshire and the Humber↵ "

Comment: In your question the desired item is the 4th item of `<ul class="selection-list selection-tree-list">`. If it's always the case, the answer is easy...

Comment: Have you tried `driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelectorAll("[id='GOS--/40']")[0].textContent;''')`

Comment: @JackFleeting unfortunately it's not always the same required item or I could just have hardcoded this in and used the id.  I am a tester and we pass through data via csv into Selenium Webdriver.  This data can change as the background data gets updated regularly and we have different versions of data that can be passed through the website. We use it as an automated way of testing the data is being pulled through as expected as well as using the data to automate report generation by inputting the selections to generate reports.

Comment: @supputuri that just results in an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried.

Comment: I Just posted the output images in my answer. As I can't do it in the comment.

Comment: @supputuri I tried the code you mentioned above: `driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelectorAll("[id='GOS--/40']")[0].textContent;''')`

Comment: @Redflame Are you still looking for the answer. If you are looking to extract only the parent text (li text only) then I developed a method which I can share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a tough one. The problem is that you have a number of similar options all containing "Section" in some flavor and it's hard to distinguish them apart. What adds to this is that each one contains a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` which means that `normalize-space()` won't work (directly) either.

But... I found that the below XPath will work.

```
//li[normalize-space()='Section\u00a0']
```

[`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) removes whitespace (but not `&nbsp`) so you have to add it in there with `\u00a0`. I've tested this locally and it's working.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but thank you for the comprehensive answer

Comment: I used the exact HTML that you posted... what happened when you used it? Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) will strip leading and trailing whitespace "allowed by the [S](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S) production in XML": `S    ::=    (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+`

Comment: @Alejandro Is that a question or a statement or ??? It seems incomplete. You just posted a bunch of quoted text. `normalize-space()` will not strip out non-breaking spaces. It doesn't treat non-breaking spaces as whitespace for whatever reason. You can try for yourself, if that's your question.

Comment: I'm using XPath Helper to check the xpath and used part of my original xpath: `//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul//li[normalize-space()='Section\u00a0']` It returned a result of [NULL]  I don't think I can post a link to the page for security reasons

Comment: @Redflame You have added to my XPath and I have no idea if what you have added is correct. Try just what I have posted. If the HTML you posted is correct, it will work because I tested it myself.

Comment: @JeffC sorry I tried it both ways the way you posted and with part of the original xpath and neither returned a result

Comment: @Redflame Then the HTML you posted is not correct. I just tried it again and it works fine for me. There's something else going on. A link to the page would solve all these issues. Are you sure this isn't in an IFRAME?

Comment: @JeffC How can I check whether it is in an IFRAME? Apologies for any ignorance, I'm very new to coding.

Comment: @JeffC `normalize-space` should never leave a trailing `#xA`. Also, entity references are expanded in the infoset, unless the parser is not validating. In such case it might leave an [unexpanded entity reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-infoset-20040204/#infoitem.rse).

Comment: @Alejandro Take the HTML posted in the question and paste it into an HTML file. Open that HTML file in Chrome and run `$x("normalize-space(//li[@id='GOS--/40'])")` in the dev tools. You will see `"Section "` but you can't tell what that last space is until you run `$x("normalize-space(//li[@id='GOS--/40'])").charCodeAt(7)` which returns the ASCII code of the 7th char, which is `160` which is a non-breaking space. `normalize-space()` is not removing the non-breaking space.

Comment: @Redflame You find the element you want and then go up the DOM and make sure there is no `IFRAME` tag in the parent chain.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks the only IFRAME mentioned is for the XPath Helper that I'm using

Comment: @JeffC you are rigth. ASCII character 160, `&nbsp;` or `&NonBreakingSpace;` HTML entity reference,  `&#x000A0;` or `&#160;` HTML/XML character reference is not a white space "allowed by the S production in XML"

Comment: @JeffC I retried this within my actual code instead of the XPath Helper and it worked. Of course with it being code for whitespace it only shows up as a space in XPath Helper not \u00a0! Thank you so much for resolving my issue.  I did have to add back in the first part of my code for it to work, therefore the actual xpath that worked for me is: `//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul/li[normalize-space()='Section\u00a0']`

Answer (score 0):

Try following `xpath` see if it helps.

```
 //li[starts-with(@id,'GOS')][@class='nodecollapsed item parent-node xh-highlight']
```

OR

```
  //li[@class='nodecollapsed item parent-node xh-highlight'][@xpath='1']
```

Comment: The top one worked if I edited it a little, however it's using the id 'GOS' instead of the text 'Section' of the element required.  `//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul//li[starts-with(@id,'GOS')]`  However I need to use the text as that is what is displayed in the front end and it is used to feed in data to test with, which can differ depending on which version of data is being used at the time.  I'll edit my question to include the element properties for further information.

Comment: @Redflame : have you tried this : `//div[@aria-hidden='false']//ul//li[contains(text(),'Section')]`

Comment: Yes that's what is listed as what I'm currently using in my question.  However I don't want to use that as it returns partial matches instead of exact matches.

Comment: @Redflame : your update isn't clear.can you post fresh html ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but to be clear I require the exact text selection to be made from the innerText or innerHTML of the element if that is possible, not the id.  I am already using contains, but that results in partial matches being returned e.g. instead of just 'Section', I will get 'Section', 'Country Section', 'Section 1' etc

Comment: @Redflame - can you post a longer xml including those portions that result in partial matches? It's difficult to see the issues without it.

Comment: @JackFleeting Is this what you mean?: `/html[@class='no-js ']/body[@class='bodyClass-full-width chrome modal-open']/div[@class='ContentBlock']/div[@id='baseDialog']/div[@class='selection-list-dialog modal-dialog Dialog']/div[@class='modal-content']/div[@id='base']/div[@class='pull-left selection-tree-container']/ul[@class='selection-list selection-tree-list']/li[contains(text(),'Section')]`

Comment: @Redflame - I was referring to the xml part that contains the "bad results" - like "Country Section", etc.

Comment: @JackFleeting sorry I'm very new to coding, I've updated my comment above, with the longer xpath if that's what you meant? Or do you mean the code displayed when I inspect the element or view the page source?

Comment: @Redflame - the code displayed when you view the page source - the part the includes the `<li>` tag in your answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting Thanks, please find it in the question, it is the node which mentions only 'Section' that should be selected.  But want to be able to select it using the text 'Section' instead of the id 'GOS--40'  - I was unable to add as a comment as it's too long

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below XPath to find a section node

Try if it helps

`//li[@id='GOS--/40'][contains(text(),'Section')]`

Comment: I've added further information to my question, as I can't use the id of the element

Answer (score 0):

Let me throw my hat into the ring....

```
//li[(normalize-space(text()) = 'Section')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I don't know if you saw JeffC's answer above, but think it could have something to do with the issue of the non-breaking space &nbsp;

Comment: @Redflame - I did; the strange thing is that his suggestion (`//li[normalize-space()='Section\u00a0']`) doesn't work for me either; but `//li[normalize-space((text())='Section']` does. Can't explain it.

Comment: neither appear to work for me, so I'll keep trying.  Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Redflame - no worry; this is the most fun I've had in a long time :D; forget normalized text - try this `//div/ul/li[text()=' Section ']` and let me know.

Comment: At least your having fun! This hasn't worked either I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method that will fetch the text from the parent only. (exclude the text in the child(ren))

In Python:

```
def get_pure_element_text(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

This method will iterate all the firstChild (direct children) and extract all text from all the text nodes.

**In this context** If you want to retrieve the text of li which have the id `GOS--/40` then use the method as below.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='GOS--/40']")
print(get_pure_element_text(element))
```

Sharing this method, at least might help the others (if not the OP in this context).

**C# implementation:**(not tested)

```
string get_pure_text(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element){
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    return (string)js.ExecuteScript(""""
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element");
```

Usage:

```
string output = get_pure_text(driver,element)
```

Comment: Thanks @supputuri would the code be similar for c#?

Comment: Included the c# implemenation, let me know how it goes. I did not checked the method as I don't have the C# environment on my machine.