# How to escape &nbsp; symbol in xpath selection (normalize-space())

Tags: html, selenium, google-chrome, dom, xpath

For example, I have a list of items (categories) on the html page like:

```
<a href="">Category1</a>
<a href="">Category2&nbsp;</a>
<a href="">Category3</a>
```

I want to get an exact match of Category2. I use XPATH for that:

```
//a[normalize-space(text())='Category2']
```

The `normalize-space()` method is used to remove spaces, but it doesn't work when the link has `&nbsp;` instead of a normal space character.

So, how can I normalize-space of `&nbsp;` using XPath 1.0 to match a link with Category2 in the text?

Comment: you need to use contains in your xpath.

Comment: XPath itself does not have any way of writing special characters such as NBSP using an escape convention. But you can use the escape conventions of the host language, for example `\u00A0` in Java or Javascript, or `&#xa0;` in XML/XSLT. You can then remove NBSP characters (or convert them to ordinary spaces) using the XPath translate() function.

Comment: @MichaelKay, lkinAlibayli need to do that in selenium, not in XML/XSLT.

Comment: @MichaelKay is right. `\u00A0` character is not part of the characters covers by the "space" production of XML grammar, thus the `normalize-space()` function doesn't trim and normalize NBSP. This is also cover in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355770/how-can-i-find-the-exact-value-using-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-for-text-that-c/55359370#comment97447308_55359370

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the exact value using xpath in selenium webdriver for text that contains &nbsp;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355770/how-can-i-find-the-exact-value-using-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-for-text-that-c)

Answer (score 2):

Try with **contains**:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Category2')]
```

You can use **start-with**:

```
//a[starts-with(normalize-space(text()),'Category2')]
```

You can try this:

```
//a[normalize-space(text())='Category2\u00a0']
```

You don't need to use normalize-space in this case:

```
//a[text()='Category2\u00a0']
```

Comment: No, it can cause problems, because there are other categories upper which can contain the same words in the text. And in case they will match, I will select the wrong category. I just need to escape the &nbsp; and make an exact match

Comment: Same text contains 'Category2' ?

Comment: The Category2 is just an example, on the HTML page I work with, there are more than 200 categories with different names and there can be such as:
`
Category2&nbsp;
and
Category2New
`
And I need exactly only one which is Category2 (I don't want to take spaces and other space-like symbols into consideration).

Comment: @IlkinAlibayli i updated my answer did you try with start-with ?

Comment: I can't use start with also, because I can have this symbol anywhere in the string... Also in the front of the string.
I tried both of methods before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191228/discussion-between-dhru-soni-and-ilkin-alibayli).

Comment: XPath does not recognize backslash as anything special.

Comment: @MichaelKay please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347274/search-for-text-with-symbols-via-xpath as it show supported.

Comment: `//a[text()='Category2\u00a0']` works with Selenium version 3.141.0, chrome Version 73.0.3683.86, ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68